# How to Pass Negative Integer to COM/OLE Function?

Tags: c++, mfc, com, atl, variant

I am working on a Microsoft Word Add-In based on C++/ATL in Visual Studio 2010.  I also am using the MFC-based `COleDispatchDriver` and supporting classes and used Visual Studio's ClassWizard to generate wrapper classes from the Microsoft Word type library.  A sample wrapper for the Selection.Move function generated by the ClassWizard is below.

```
long Move(VARIANT * Unit, VARIANT * Count)
{
    long result;
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT ;
    InvokeHelper(0x6d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms, Unit, Count);
    return result;
}
```

For functions like the one above, I have also written helper functions to take care of the VARIANT argument passing, as shown below.

```
long Move(int Unit, int Count)
{
      long result;
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT ;

      VARIANT vaUnit;
      ::VariantInit(&vaUnit);
      vaUnit.vt = VT_I4;
      vaUnit.iVal = Unit;

      VARIANT vaCount;
      ::VariantInit(&vaCount);
      vaCount.vt = VT_INT;
      vaCount.iVal = Count;

      InvokeHelper(0x6d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms, &vaUnit, &vaCount);

      ::VariantClear(&vaUnit);
      ::VariantClear(&vaCount);

      return result;
}
```

When I call my function with a positive integer for the `Count` parameter, Word responds correctly, e.g. the following function call will move the selection "forward" (toward the end of the document) by one character.

```
m_oSelection.Move(1 /* wdCharacter */, 1);
```

However, if I try to move the selection one character "backward" (toward the beginning of the document) with the following function call, Word does not respond as expected.

```
m_oSelection.Move(1 /* wdCharacter */, -1);
```

It "seems" like the Word automation is treating the integer as an unsigned integer and my -1 value becomes 65535 causing the selection to jump forward.  Inspecting the `vaCount` variant on the line with the `InvokeHelper` function call, the VS debugger shows the `.iVal` value as -1, but the "value" of the `vaCount` variant is being shown as 65535.

What am I missing to appropriately pass the negative integer as part of the COM function call?

Comment: Underlying function should probably not support negative value. Maybe an other method or different `Unit` argument...

Comment: Use `int16_t(65535)` to get `-1`, or `VT_I2` (instead of `VT_I4`) to specify 16bit integer.

Comment: `vaCount` is using `VT_INT` instead of `VT_I4`, like `vaUnit` uses. Does the problem go away if you change `VT_INT` to `VT_I4`?  The `.iVal` field is only valid for `VT_I2`, `VT_I4` uses `.lVal` and `VT_INT` uses `.intVal` instead. Storing a 32bit `-1` in `.lVal` or `.intVal` will fill all 4 bytes with all 1 bits, which when truncated to 16bits in `.iVal` will still be all 1s, thus still `-1`. A *signed* 16bit `-1` is the same bits as an *unsigned*  16bit `65535`. So you need to figure out why your *signed* values are being *interpretted* as *unsigned* values.

Comment: The original helper function used `VT_I4` for `vaCount` with the result described above.  The code I posted was from an experiment to see what happened if I switched to using `VT_INT`, which the code above did not function as expected.  However, when I fixed the `.iVal/.lVal` bug, the code now functions as expected!  As to why `VT_I4` will not let me pass a negative integer, it remains a mystery... but @RemyLebeau if you move your comment to an answer, I would love to mark it as correct!

Comment: @user986713 done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem is that you are misusing `VARIANT`.

You are setting `vaCount`'s `vt` field to `VT_INT` <sup>1</sup> but are then assigning your `int` value to its `.iVal` field instead of its `.intVal` field.  The `.iVal` field is a 16bit `short` that is used for `VT_I2`, whereas `.intVal` is a 32bit `int` used with `VT_INT`.

Likewise, you are setting `vaUnit`'s `vt` to `VT_I4` but then are assigning your `int` value to its `.iVal` field as well, instead of its `.lVal` field, which is a 32bit `long`.

<sup>1: why you are using `VT_INT` at all, instead of the more traditional `VT_I4`?</sup>

Try this instead:

```
long Move(int Unit, int Count)
{
      long result;
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT ;

      VARIANT vaUnit;
      ::VariantInit(&vaUnit);
      vaUnit.vt = VT_I4;
      vaUnit.lVal = Unit;

      VARIANT vaCount;
      ::VariantInit(&vaCount);
      vaCount.vt = VT_I4;
      vaCount.lVal = Count;

      InvokeHelper(0x6d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms, &vaUnit, &vaCount);

      ::VariantClear(&vaUnit);
      ::VariantClear(&vaCount);

      return result;
}
```

That being said, I suggest you use the [`CComVariant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomvariant-class) or [`_variant_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class) wrapper class instead of using `VARIANT` directly, and let it handle these kind of details for you.  Also, because `InvokeHelper()` throws an exception on failure, so let the wrapper call `VariantClear()` for you when it goes out of scope:

```
long Move(int Unit, int Count)
{
      long result;
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT ;

      CComVariant vaUnit(Unit);
      CComVariant vaCount(Count);

      InvokeHelper(0x6d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms, &vaUnit, &vaCount);

      return result;
}
```

```
long Move(int Unit, int Count)
{
      long result;
      static BYTE parms[] = VTS_PVARIANT VTS_PVARIANT ;

      _variant_t vaUnit(Unit);
      _variant_t vaCount(Count);

      InvokeHelper(0x6d, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, parms, &vaUnit, &vaCount);

      return result;
}
```

Comment: Using the CComVariant helper class would have saved me a lot of headache!  Thanks for the helpful comment and incredibly thorough and helpful answer!